# Rendering an Angular Component into the DOM without Component wrapper

Tags: angular

I have this button, that I use in multiple places throughout my site.

Because of that, I moved it to Component. I call it `GetInvolvedButtonComponent`.

However, I can't use this Component right now because Angular is wrapping a special HTML tag around it. That cause issue.

How do I render the HTML straight into the section without it being wrapped in that tag?

Here's what I have thus far:

**`get-involved-button.component.html`**

```
<!-- TODO: This is going to route to another page called "Get Involved" -->
<a class="btn btn-primary center" routerLink="/contact">Get Involved!</a>
```

**`get-involved-button.component.ts`**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "[get-involved-button]",
  templateUrl: "./get-involved-button.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./get-involved-button.component.css"],
})
export class GetInvolvedButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

When I inspect the DOM element in the developer console, this is what I see:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the wrapper html screenshot or code ?

Comment: If it is a component, there is no way to avoid having an html tag for the component. A workaround is to use some css that practically ignores the container element: ':host { display: contents; }` Check for compatibility.

Comment: @alou, really you can use as selector a name between `[` and `]` and you can applied to any html tag, e.g. a div

Comment: May I see what that looks like, for future reference? It's been literally years since I've done any Angular, and I didn't know this

Comment: @MikeWarren, he means using as component selector an actual html element, eg [div] which will practically render your component for all div tags. I don't know if that's really an option, but it would work.

Answer (score 1):

Per @alou's comment on here, I just had to

```
:host { display:contents }
```

inside the component's CSS file, and it work.